# Can I play my far cry 3 (Xbox 360 edition) on my laptop?

Tags: far-cry-3

Ok so for Christmas. I got an Acer laptop. My question is, will I be able to play Far Cry 3 on my laptop with a wireless 360 controller?

Comment: You should clarify your question before it gets closed. Are you asking about running Xbox game disks on PCs? Emulating software only? Or controller use?

Answer (score 2):

**No**

xbox games are not cross-platform and, unless you install an emulator wich is not what you are looking for, you will not be able to play xbox or playstation game on PC.
It's just technically impossible to do so.

The xbox controller is ok, if you have the usb connector for the controller you can play most of the PC games with it on your laptop ( check for compatibility ).

In case of far cry 3, if you buy the game on PC, you will be able to use the controller instead of the keyboard

Comment: You should edit your answer, NO is not the right word here. The answer ist YES with the second part oft your answer about the gamepad, he did not ask anything about a Xbox game on a Windows platform

Comment: @Nitro.de His question title clearly states 'Xbox 360 edition,' so this answer is correct as it stands.

Comment: You can not play the 360 version on a pc or laptop. You can play a PC version of Far Cry 3 on a PC or Laptop WITH a wireless 360 controller provided he use a wireless 360 controller adapter for the PC but not the game in an Xbox 360.

There we go.

Comment: I see there is a bit of a confusion. I edited the answer, I hope that clears things out